# iPad possibly stolen, not appearing in Find my iPhone, what options do I have?

Tags: ios, ipad, find-my-iphone

I suspect that my cleaner has stolen my iPad Pro. I restored from an iCloud backup of an iPhone. It does not show up in find my iPhone on safari or my iPhone. I only had the device a week and hadn't had the time to properly set it up. I have definitely signed into iCloud on the device though.

- Is there any thing I can do to track it down, send a message etc without Find my iPhone?
- Can I reauthorise it so my iMessages aren't sent there?

Before I definitely had my iMessages and other notifications being sent there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from your question whether you have or haven't set up the iPad Pro with the Find my iPhone feature. However, at the risk of oversimplifying things, if the device:

- doesn't appear in your devices list either on Find my iPhone or on [iCloud Find](https://icloud.com/find) (which is how I interpret your question) then it's almost certainly not set up with Find my iPhone. If this is the case, then you should definitely [change your Apple ID password](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201355)! This will prevent anyone else who may have accessed your iPad Pro from deleting your data from iCloud or making other unwanted changes.
- does appear, but is just showing as offline, then it is set up with Find my iPhone but is just currently not online.

To answer your question on whether you can send a message to it, and assuming it's not set up with Fine my iPhone, then you can still send a message but not via Find my iPhone. Instead, because you were getting iMessages on the device, all you need to do is send an iMessage from your iPhone to whatever number/email address/account was being used on the iPad Pro to receive messages.

**IMPORTANT**

Before doing anything else I would heed my advice above re [changing your Apple ID password](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201355), unless of course you do want to send an iMessage to it first. But if that's the case, then I'd do it ASAP and reset your password.

Comment: Changing the Apple ID password will definitely stop iMessages being delivered on any device until that device has the new password entered.